# Android reconnect to WebSocket with callbackFlow

Tags: android, kotlin, websocket, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I am working on a multiplayer game server. To do that I implemented an okhttp websocket. I use `callbackFlow` to handle the callback functions like `onMessage` or `onFailure`. This is my repo code:

```kotlin
class WebSocketRepository {

    fun socketEventsFlow(): Flow<GameServerResponse> = callbackFlow {

        val socketListener = object : WebSocketListener() {

            override fun onMessage(webSocket: WebSocket, text: String) {
                val message = Gson().fromJson(text, GameServerResponse::class.java)
                trySendBlocking(message)
            }
        }

        attachWebSocketListener(socketListener)
        awaitClose {
            socket.close(1000, "application in Background")
        }
    }

    private fun attachWebSocketListener(listener: WebSocketListener) {
        val client = OkHttpClient()
        val request = Request
            .Builder()
            .url("ws://10.0.2.2:8080")
            .build()

        socket = client.newWebSocket(request, listener)
    }
}
```

I then forward pass this Flow through the viewModel to the Activity to for example launch a new fragment. This is the viewModel's code:

```kotlin
class MainActivityViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: WebSocketRepository
) : ViewModel() {
    val events = repository.socketEventsFlow()
}
```

I finally collect the flow in the activity like this:

```kotlin
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    private val viewModel: MainActivityViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)


        lifecycleScope.launch {
            lifecycle.repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
                viewModel.events.collect { event ->
                    //Do stuff here
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There are two problems though.

1. If the user closes the app (in the background, not fully terminate it), the socket is closed due to the `awaitClose` statement. I could easily fix that by setting `Lifecycle.state.STARTED` to `Lifecycle.state.CREATED`. I worry though that if I do that I would run into problems. For example navigating while the app is in the background. I don't want to create a new socket every time the user closes the app though.
2. The second problem is the "more important" one. How do I correctly handle reconncetions with this approach? If for example the internet connections drops the server will detect that the client is not there anymore and terminate the connection. I want the app to try to automatically reconnect though. But I have no clue how to implement that. I believe that I would somehow have to re-collect the viewModel's event Flow. But I have no idea on how to actually do that. Is there a better way to handle reconnections?